# Insert a string at a specified index in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, string, insert

I would like to insert a string at a specified index in a row of an array by 2 steps. From a matrix:

```
A=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
   [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
   [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
   [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
   [4, 5, 6, 7, 7],
   [5, 7, 6, 8, 9]]
```

I would like to receive:

```
A=[[**x**, 2, 3, 4, 5],
   [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
   [**x**, 1, 2, 2, 3],
   [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
   [**x**, 5, 6, 7, 7],
   [5, 7, 6, 8, 9]]
```

or:

```
A=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
   [**x**, 7, 8, 9, 10],
   [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
   [**x**, 3, 4, 5, 6],
   [4, 5, 6, 7, 7],
   [**x**, 7, 6, 8, 9]]
```

or:

```
A=[[1, 2, **x**, 4, 5],
   [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
   [1, 1, **x**, 2, 3],
   [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
   [4, 5, **x**, 7, 7],
   [5, 7, 6, 8, 9]]
```

and so on. I hope you understand my question (I used bold letters in order to distinguish strings). If I try:

```
def r(l):
    for i in l[::2]:
        i.insert(0, 'x')
    return l
```

it returns:

> 'int' object has no attribute 'insert'

but I suppose it isn't my very valuable comment, if I end up with no clue how I can complete the task...

Comment: No exception occurs when I try running your code—so it's unclear what you are asking. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It also looks like you want to _replace_ values, not insert them into the list.

Comment: As I have mentioned - I made a mistake in my example matrix. Thank you for your adice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple indexing instead of `insert`:

```
def r(l, idx=0):
    for i in l[::2]:
        i[idx] = 'x'
    return l

>>> print(r(A))
[['x', 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ['x', 1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], ['x', 5, 6, 7, 7], [5, 7, 6, 8, 9]]
```

The `idx` argument gives you the index where you want to change the entry. For example, if you wanted to change the 3rd element to `x`, then use:

```
>>> print(r(A, idx=2))
[[1, 2, 'x', 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 1, 'x', 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 'x', 7, 7], [5, 7, 6, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Thank you. I have noticed that I used a different matrix with an erroneous elements. When I changed them, my presented above method also worked.